# Not saving the HABTM Association when creating a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have those two Models, in a HABTM Relationship:

**The Project is using Rails 4, so no attr_accessible tags**

#### wine.rb

```
class Wine < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :pairings, class_name: 'Food', join_table: 'foods_wines', association_foreign_key: 'food_id'
  has_many :images, as: :attachable, class_name: 'Asset', dependent: :delete_all
end
```

#### food.rb

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :wines, class_name: "Wine", join_table: "foods_wines", foreign_key: "food_id"
end
```

I created the Join Table with this migration:

```
create_table(:foods_wines, :id => false) do |t|
  t.integer :food_id
  t.integer :wine_id
end

add_index :foods_wines, [:food_id, :wine_id]
```

When I try to create the new Relation in the Rails Console, it does not seem to be saving the HABTM Relationship.

> @wine.pairings.create(:name => "Seafood")

it does not seem to be saving the HABTM Relation -> When I restart the console, the relation is gone - I also checked inside the DB, where I get an empty table for the **foods_wines** table.

Am I missing something crucial here?

Comment: Where are your attr_accessible tags?

Comment: Rails 4, strong params take that away.

Comment: Please try to run `@wine.pairings.create!(:name => "Seafood")` to see if you have any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to replace :

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :pairings, class_name: 'Food', join_table: 'foods_wines', association_foreign_key: 'food_id'
```

with :

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :pairings, class_name: 'Food', join_table: 'foods_wines', foreign_key: 'wine_id'
```

in `wine.rb`, because you have to specify the `foreign key` of this class (Wine).